# Connecting atmega328 to PGM03A

Tags: microcontroller

I just got Pololu PGM03A programmer and ATMEGA328P-PU chip. The problem is that the programmer doesn't come with any 'case' where I can put the chip on so I'm guessing I have to wire it manually. I followed this guide:

[image]

Only difference is that I got 6 pin cable.

I double checked the wiring, exact match, but when I power up the programmer, the red LED is blinking, meaning it can't find the chip. I replaced the chip, but still the same thing happens.

I noticed that this person has extra power/ground connections to the chip:

[image]

Is this what I'm missing? can I safely connect it like this without burning it down? thanks!

UPDATE: I tried to connect the additional VCC and GROUND connections, but still nothing changes.

Comment: Where are you getting Vcc and GND from? The manual for your programmer specifically states that you can't power the target chip from the USB 5V or it won't work, so if you're doing that, you'll need an external 5V supply.

Comment: You need to supply an external 5V/GND to both AVCC/AGND and VCC/GND of the chip. You also should have a pull up resistor on the reset pin (10k or so between RESET and VCC). If you have previously programmed the fuses to external oscillator, you also need to connect an oscillator or crystal to the XTAL pins.